# Assigning an AWS IAM role to an AWS EKS Jenkins Agent Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I'm configuring an AWS EKS-based Jenkins master with different agents. Jenkins can spin up new pods just fine. The problem is when I try to assign an IAM role to that pod through the Service account. It just doesn't pick it up. It worked two days ago, but I had to delete the jenkins_home directory, so I'm starting from scratch again.

The service account is like:

```
$ kubectl get serviceaccount -n jenkins jenkins-agents -o yaml 
apiVersion: v1
automountServiceAccountToken: false
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:role/clz_deployer_role
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-22T15:19:55Z"
  name: jenkins-agents
  namespace: jenkins
  resourceVersion: "145998"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/jenkins/serviceaccounts/jenkins-agents
  uid: 8d55df19-140d-4703-bc61-886a25a20eac
secrets:
- name: jenkins-agents-token-mmxb8
```

and I pass the name of the service account to the Pod configuration:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins/label: jenkins-slave-aws-cli
  name: awsclislave
  # annotations:
  #   eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1111111111111:role/clz_deployer_role
spec:
  containers:
    - image: pquery/jnlp-slave-docker:latest
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: awsclislave
      command:
        - cat
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512Mi
          cpu: 512m
        requests:
          memory: 512Mi
          cpu: 512m
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/jenkins
          name: workspace-volume
          readOnly: false
      workingDir: /home/jenkins
  hostNetwork: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  restartPolicy: Never
  serviceAccount: jenkins-agents
  volumes:
    - emptyDir:
        medium: ""
      name: workspace-volume
```

I tried with annotations (commented) but it didn't work either. The error message is always the same:

```
com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::1111111111111:assumed-role/shared_services20200922074522597500000008/i-0c1c41c96e96e82df is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::2222222222222:role/clz_aws_cicd_access (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: bfe43133-13c1-4cdb-b4b9-626cf11def58; Proxy: null)
```

It's trying to use the instance role to perform the operation instead of the role attached to the Service Account. Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: What is the instance role? The message says that it lacks `sts:AssumeRole` permissions.

Comment: The instance role shouldn't be related. It should be picking up the Task role I'm giving it, but it's using the instance role by default. I'm using the Kubernetes plugin in case it changes something. The ultimate goal is to execute the agents in AWS Fargate

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on clz_deployer_role IAM role trust relationship, where the namespace was wrong. More specifically, inside condition:

"Condition": {
"StringEquals": {
"oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/C1B7F80BE15AC5C89956D55EF7E3FFC5:sub": "system:serviceaccount:jenkins:jenkins-agents"
}
}

The "system:serviceaccount:jenkins:jenkins-agents" string is "system:serviceaccount::<service_account_name>"
and namespace was pointing to "default", when it was in "jenkins"
It works great now